# 12V adapter rated for 4A has trouble outputting 0.12A

Tags: power-supply

I just bought a new 12V adapter on Amazon and tested the performance. It came with, what they call, a led connector tip which has a postive and negative connection point making it possible to connect a resistor to it. Here is the link to the product:

https://www.amazon.nl/dp/B07F1KL48J?ref=ppx_yo2ov_dt_b_product_details&th=1

I attached an image showing how I connected the resistor to the adapter. The resistor was a 100 ohm resistor so I expected to measure 0.12A of current with my multimeter. However, the current fluctuated between 60mA and 90mA, never actually reaching 0.12A. When I measured the voltage, I saw it fluctuating between 6V and 10V. I also see the LED on the adapter turning on and off. When I do the same thing with a 1000 ohm resistor, the output voltage is around 14V and the current is around 0.012A, as expected. When I use a 10 ohm resistor, the output voltage doesn't come anywhere near 1V and the current fluctuates between 0.1A and 0.3A. Does anyone know why the adapter has difficulties outputting the expected current? Is the adapater not working propperly or is this normal behaviour?

[image]

Comment: It could be normal or it could be faulty it is hard to tell from only a single load measurement. Some basic feedback: (1), a 100ohm 5% resistor could be as low as 95ohm or as high as 105 ohm, furthermore 90ma is only 25% less than the expected 120ma. Therefore, it is good to confirm assumptions like the actual voltage and resistance and ammeter resolution . (2) power supplies rated for 4A in some designs may indeed struggle to regulate lower loads, this would be visible on the voltage output. A good datasheet is critical to confirm performance is within spec.

Comment: I did not mention this in the original post but I did test the resistance of the resistor with a multimeter. It measures 100.1 ohms. I also tested with other resistor values. At 1k ohm, the output voltage measure 14V and the current is about 0.012A, as expected. When using a 10 ohm resistor, the output voltage doesn't come anywhere near 1V.

Comment: _"When I use a 10 ohm resistor, the output voltage doesn't come anywhere near 1V."_ - That should draw ~1.2A @12V. The power supply is supposed to be compatible with 1A and 2A 12V supplies. Less than 1V suggests that it's faulty.

Comment: Your tests seem fine. I note that this it's a 3rd party Amazon seller which makes it the equivalent of eBay or Banggood.  A lot of that stuff is made overseas and has faked CE marks.  You can run down the manufacturer and see if they actually look like a manufacturer, many I've chased turn out to be a private mailbox company or apartment.

Comment: If you measure the current, then measure the voltage drop over a known resistor, because the Multimeter has an internal resistor too, to measure the current. Could you weigh the power supply? If possible without the weight of the cables. Then stick a 2mm cooper wire directly into the DC hollow socket and try to measure without the adaptor. Possibly there is a resistance (bad solder connection) inside of the adaptor.

Comment: The reviews were good, so I think you have a defective unit. But it might need a capacitor on the output. It seems to be designed as a laptop charger or power supply.

Comment: Did you at any time measure a current using the "A" position, probe lead plugged left? Went on to measure voltage, forgot to plug probe lead back right?

Answer (score 0):

Many low-cost switching power supplies have a minimum load requirement.  A common value is 10% of the "main" output's full rated current.  For example, a supply rated for 5 V at 100 A and +/-12 V at 10 A each has a minimum load requirement of 5 A on the 5 V output.

Pile on more load resistors in parallel.  Load it to something greater than 0.5 A and see what happens.

Comment: Very intersting. I did not know that many power supplies had a minimum load requirement. However, it seems that the power supply should be above the minimum load required? If I connect it to a 10 ohm resistor, the current should be 1.2A at 12V. That sounds like it should be above the minimum. So I don't think adding a second 10 ohm resistor in order to lower the total resistance to 5 ohm, would do anything  as the load is already quite high. I also tested with a 1k ohm resistor and that resulted in a Vout of 14V and 0.012A. Am I confusing two things? Is current drawn not the same as load?

Comment: I just found out that there is something called a "no load power supply". No load power supplies are designed to operate reliably without a minimum load requirement. This sounds like something that would be able to fix the problem when qorking with very low loads.  FYI, this power supply was given as an example. https://www.meanwell-web.com/en-gb/ac-dc-industrial-desktop-adaptor-with-pfc-output-gst120a12--r7b